# Interspace program in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

```
insert :: Eq(a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insert m n [] = []
insert m n (x:xs) | m==x = n : x : insert m n xs  
                 | otherwise = x : insert m n xs
```

The `insert` function above is a working function that inserts a value `n` into a list before all instances of a value `m`.

I need help writing an `interspace` function that inserts a value `n` between all values `m` and `q` in a list. This is what I have so far:

```
 interspace :: Eq(a) => a -> a -> a->[a] -> [a]

 interspace m n q[] = []

 interspace m n q (x:xs)| m==x && q==(head xs)  = n: x : insert m n (headxs)++interspace m n q (xs)

                         | otherwise = x : interspace m n q xs
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Presumably "n" should be inserted whenever the sequence "[m,q]" appears in the list. So what are you getting when you try it? You do appear to be thinking along the right lines, but "insert" is not necessary, and "headxs" is wrong. Perhaps you need to consider the pattern "(x1:x2:xs)"

Comment: Create a new array in length `2n-1` whereas `n` is the length of the `sourceArray` and map it as follows; if index is odd insert the intersperse item; if even insert `sourceArray[i/2]`

Comment: Can you explain clearly, in English, what each function is expected to do, and give several examples of arguments and results (including corner cases)? I have no idea what `insert` and `interspace` are supposed to mean in this context, and reading incorrect code for implementing `interspace` seems unlikely to help me figure that out.

Comment: The insert function replaces one element in the list with another element. The insert is just the name of the function. The interspace function should add an element in the list of different number between m and q

Answer (score 1):

Since you will only be adding values to the front of the list, your `insert` function is unnecessary. `(:)` will suffice instead. Much like in `insert`, we pass recursively over the list. Since we want to check if two values match at a time and will also call the function recursively on different lists based on whether or not we find a match, it's a good idea to pattern match `(x1:x2:xs)` rather than just `(x:xs)`.

If `m` matches `x1` and `q` matches `x2`, we place the onto the head of the list and call `interspace` recursively on the rest of the list. If they do not mach, we call `interspace` on `(x2:xs)`.

```
 interspace :: Eq a => a -> a -> a-> [a] -> [a]
 interspace m n q []         = []
 interspace m n q [x]        = [x]
 interspace m n q (x1:x2:xs) | m == x1 && q == x2 = m : n : q : interspace m n q xs
                             | otherwise          = x1 : interspace m n q (x2:xs)
```

Example usage:

```
ghci>> interspace 1 2 1 [1,1,2,1,1]
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
ghci>> interspace 1 2 1 [1,1,3]
[1,2,1,3]
ghci>> interspace 1 2 1 [1,2,4,2]
[1,2,4,2]
ghci>> interspace 1 2 1 [1]
[1]
ghci>> interspace 1 2 1 []
[]
```

Comment: Non-exhaustive patterns in function interspace error

Comment: What is your input? If you paste this into a blank haskell file, do you still encounter the same non-exhaustive patterns error?

Comment: interspace.hs:1:2: error:
    Illegal type signature: ‘Eq a =>
                             a -> a -> a -> [a] -> [a] interspace m n q []’
      Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables

interspace.hs:3:2: error:
    Multiple declarations of ‘interspace’
    Declared at: interspace.hs:1:2
                 interspace.hs:3:2

Comment: parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5' now

Comment: So you're only encountering the parse error now? And what is your input? ex. `interspace 1 2 1 [1,1]` Also, what are you expecting as output for something like `interspace 1 2 1 [1,1,1]`? Can the middle `1` be part of a pair twice?